# Gnome popup menu overflow

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I just changed the theme on my desktop and the contents of the wifi password prompt overflows the menu.

[image]

What modifications could I make to the gnome-shell.css file to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the latest version of your theme. If yes, you should contact developers of this theme via their issue tracker (Github, Gitlab, etc.) and provide this screenshot, your Linux distribution and version of Gnome 3 you use.

Developers can either fix this issue right away or tell you which CSS is causing this problem and you can fix it yourself.